# How to extract a centred, cropped inner image section having a given aspect ratio

Tags: imagemagick

In the illustration below, the blue rectangles represent arbitrary source images. For each image, I want to extract a section (shown in red) which is

- of a specified aspect ratio (in this example, they are all 3:2)
- as large as possible while fitting within the source image
- centred within the source image

How can I do this with ImageMagick command-line tools?

[image]

Comment: Do you only want horizontal crops? What is your ImageMagick version and platform?

Answer (score 1):

You can crop the largest possible 3:2 section from the center of an image with a command like this...

```
convert input.png \
   -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:(w/3)<(h/2)?w:h*3/2]x%[fx:(w/3)<(h/2)?w*2/3:h]" \
   \( xc: -distort SRT 0 \) +swap -gravity center -composite output.png
```

That uses the input image's dimensions to calculate the size of the output image, creates a blank image of those dimensions as a sort of template, then composites the input image centered over that template. The result is essentially a 3:2 image cropped from the center of the input.

Edited to add...

Here is another method that simply resets the page information to specify new canvas dimensions and offsets, then flattens the image properly located within that new canvas.

```
convert input.png \
   -set page "%[fx:(w/3)<(h/2)?w:h*3/2]x%[fx:(w/3)<(h/2)?w*2/3:h]" \
   -set page "-%[fx:(w/3)<(h/2)?0:(w-(h*3/2))/2]-%[fx:(w/3)<(h/2)?(h-(w*2/3))/2:0]" \
   -flatten output.png
```

This doesn't have to create a template image or do a composite operation, and in testing it seems to be far faster than my other suggestion above.

Comment: `@GeeMack`  Good point about using viewport and distort SRT 0. I had forgot about that for ImageMagick 6. My IM 7 formulae could be used in IM 6 in this same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want horizontal crops with `w>h` aspect, then you can do that in ImageMagick 6 as follows in Unix syntax:

Input:

[image]

```
infile="monet2.jpg"
aspect="3:2"
ww=`convert -ping "$infile" -format "%w" info:`
hh=`convert -ping "$infile" -format "%h" info:`
ratio=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$ww/$hh]" info:`
aspect1=`echo $aspect | cut -d\: -f1`
aspect2=`echo $aspect | cut -d\: -f2`
aspect=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$aspect1/$aspect2]" info:`
test=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$aspect>=$ratio?1:0]" info:`
if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then
    width=$ww
    height=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$hh*$ratio/$aspect]" info:`
else
    width=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$ww*$aspect/$ratio]" info:`
    height=$hh
fi  
convert "$infile" -gravity center -crop ${width}x${height}+0+0 +repage result.jpg
```

[image]

Input:

[image]

```
infile="barn.jpg"
aspect="3:2"
ww=`convert -ping "$infile" -format "%w" info:`
hh=`convert -ping "$infile" -format "%h" info:`
ratio=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$ww/$hh]" info:`
aspect1=`echo $aspect | cut -d\: -f1`
aspect2=`echo $aspect | cut -d\: -f2`
aspect=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$aspect1/$aspect2]" info:`
test=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$aspect>=$ratio?1:0]" info:`
if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then
    width=$ww
    height=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$hh*$ratio/$aspect]" info:`
else
    width=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:$ww*$aspect/$ratio]" info:`
    height=$hh
fi  
convert "$infile" -gravity center -crop ${width}x${height}+0+0 +repage result2.jpg
```

[image]

If on a Unix-like OS, then see my script, aspectcrop, at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html

If you provide `w<h` aspect, then the same code will crop vertically.

In ImageMagick 7, you can do it in one command line, if you provide the aspect as a fraction rather than a colon separated ratio:

```
infile="monet2.jpg"
aspect="1.5"
magick "$infile" \
-gravity center \
-crop "%[fx:$aspect>=(w/h)?w:w*$aspect/(w/h)]x%[fx:$aspect>=(w/h)?h*(w/h)/$aspect:h]+0+0" \
+repage \
result.jpg
```